# storing a dynamic dimension array list during the "scan" function in theano

Tags: python, theano

I want to make a dynamic array list during the theano `scan` function like below.

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x_var = T.dmatrix('x_var')
y_var = T.dmatrix('y_var')

def _op(y, h_tm1):
    h_next = T.concatenate([h_tm1, y.dimshuffle('x', 0)])
    return h_next

h_res, _ = theano.scan(fn=_op,
                       sequences=y_var,
                       outputs_info=x_var)

fn = theano.function(inputs=[x_var, y_var],
                     outputs=h_res)

x = np.asarray([[0, 0, 0]],
               dtype=theano.config.floatX)
y = np.asarray([[1,1,1], [2,2,2]],
               dtype=theano.config.floatX)
res = fn(x, y)
print res
```

What I want to do is in each iteration, append one vector of `y_var` to the end of the `h_tm1`, then return the new matrix. However it seems that scan can not store the dynamic dimension matrix list in the runtime?

I have found that the error happened on the line `h_next = T.concatenate([h_tm1, y.dimshuffle('x', 0)])`

The theano report the error like

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,3) into shape (1,3)", other details about this error is omitted.

Comment: I have added a few lines of `import` to your code to make it able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "unfortunately, scan expects the inputs and outputs of the inner 
function to be constant from one timestep to the next." source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/UY7bQb10Oak/discussion